# Using audioread on a MP3 File in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mp3

I have some trouble to read mp3 file in matlab.
There is the function audioread that is supposed to do the job, but it doesn't work.

```
>> [x Fs] = audioread('Corner.mp3');
*** audioread: problem reading Corner.mp3:Too many input arguments.
*** audioread: returning empty waveform
```

The function DOES work for WAV files without problem. I really don't know where do problem comes from, i searched here and using google, without success.

Have you, guys, any idea ?

EDIT : Here is the mp3 file : http://www8.zippyshare.com/v/zZQpECRF/file.html

EDIT 2 : I am using Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a) on a Windows 8 laptop.

EDIT 3 : It seems that my Matlab version is too old. Now I'm using the R2014a version and it works perfecly !

Comment: What platform are you on? What version of MATLAB? Does your MP3 file play properly in other software?

Comment: Post your MP3 file for reproducibility

Comment: Yes my mp3 file plays correctly using the windows media player. And I am using the 7.12.0 (R2011a) Matlab version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not reproducible in Matlab 2015a. As [hiandbaii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808586/802378) your Matlab version is too old. Use your MP3 file and update to a newer version of Matlab and it will work.

```
>> [x Fs] = audioread('Corner.mp3');
>> Fs
Fs =
       44100
>> size(x)
ans =
    12899250           2
```

Comment: you can download the mp3 file on the main post !

Comment: @Xema You are using the built in function right? Not something on FEX?

Comment: I had to add the audioread files after having them downloaded (not on FEX). Apparently, this is a built in function in R2012b, and not in R2011a.

Comment: @Xema Why don't you update to a later version (if you have a valid license). The reason is that the functionality of `wavplay` probably changed with the introduction of `audioread` so calling the same function may not produce a good output. This is further backed up by the `too many arguments` error because the arguments would have changed between versions.

Comment: Yeah maybe so, i'll try this when I have a higher version !

Answer (score 1):

Matlab documentation says audioread was "Introduced in R2012b". I was unable to find audioread in the official 2011a matlab documentation either

Comment: I had to download the audioread files, so maybe that is why it is not working. The audioread with .wav calls wavplay (which is supported, so it does work). However concerning .mp3, it may need to be with the R2012b Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Ellis from Labrosa (columbia) have early wrote some matlab code for importing mp3 m4a and flac files.
That will also work on older Matlab versions.
Check: http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/audioread/ 
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the problem has been solved using R2014a Matlab version (where audioread has been introduced).